# data structure for parsing Json log file in java

Tags: java, json, algorithm, search, data-structures

I am trying to parse a JSON log file in Java.
I m done with the classes and data storage.

I just need to filter it and store in proper data structure so that i dont need to access the file again and again.

Below is the example of my log file:

> {"name":"@company","hostname":"abc","pid":18624,"level":30,
>    "loggerObject":{"feature":"VC","module":"VIDEO",
>    "level":"INFO","logTime":"16:32:46",
>    "userName":"xyz","courseName":"16June2016"}
>    }

I need to filter with 4 parameters

1. Level
2. module
3. courseName
4. userName

out of these Level can be 20 or 30 and module can be video or audio.
coursename and username can be anything.

How do i design/use a data structure to store this data and reduce its search complexity?

Comment: Why don't you feed the logs into a Mongo database and query them via NoSQL queries?

Comment: Java has a built-in JSON API in the [`javax.json`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: i would say dump it to excel.
you will have everything you need there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON string using a [`JsonReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html), and then access the fields you need using a [`JsonObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html). From there you can store the data however you need.

```
JsonObject log = Json.createReader(new FileReader("log-file.txt"))
                     .readObject()
                     .getJsonObject("loggerObject");

String level      = log.getString("level"),
       module     = log.getString("module"),
       courseName = log.getString("courseName"),
       userName   = log.getString("userName");
```